# Opencv is installed via pip but can't import it in cmd

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have install opencv via pip by `pip install opencv-python` and it have been successfully installed but when I try to import it is show `The specific module could not be found`.[image]

This is the opencv's **init**.py code

`import sys
import os
 #FFMPEG dll is not found on Windows without this
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file))
from . import cv2
sys.modules['cv2'] = cv2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this [blog](https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/) and it worked for me